# How should I proceed now to make the table 'borrow' that shows relationship between member and the book he borrowed

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here are the information about two tables, namely `book` and `member`. A member is entitled to borrow a book.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `book_copies` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_pub` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `copyright_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_receive` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE member (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `year` int NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
CREATE TABLE `borrow` (
 `borrow_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'is a foreign key of book',
 `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'is a foreign key of member',
 PRIMARY KEY (`borrow_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```